# Alternative to System() for running a batch file in a program

Tags: c++, gcc, system

I want to make a system were I can run a make file and several other gcc related things within a program, basically to use gcc and compile stuff within the program. If I wrote up all the stuff I want to do to a batch file then I'd need to run that batch file from within the program.

Now everyone says `System()` calls are extremely bad because of  security and various other things. So considering I am using c++ what would be a good alternative to `System()` to run batch files. If preferable I would like the alternative to cross platform.

Thanks

Comment: If your commands are in a script, that script is pretty much platform-dependent. To run that, you can't have a cross platform solution, unless you rewrite the whole thing in C++. Including program invocations by fork()/exec() (which is again a *nix thing).

Comment: Fair point. But Lets say I had a different batch/shell script for each platform and then preprocessor commands for each platform.

Comment: The security issue isn't just that `system()` is really bad. If the string passed to `system()` is known at compile time, it's not so bad. It's just very inefficient to drop out of your own program, spin up a shell, execute a command to run another program, ... However, if the command is built at run time, and in any way based on user input, then any method of running that command is very risky, as someone could find a way to sneak something malicious into that command.

Comment: well, most likely, since you already know the scripts exist, and you already the know the platform has a shell (to run the scripts), `system` pretty much seems like the only solution.

Comment: And theres not so much of a security risk if the command is predetermined at compile time?

Comment: If you go down the path of code for each OS, look into `WinExec`, `ShellExec`, or `CreateProcess` for Windows.

Comment: Executing commands by *any* technique is risky if there's any chance a hacker could alter the command somehow (say by buffer overrun, or dodgy quoting in input (see SQL injection), or something like that). If that's not a problem then `system()` is fine, although there may be more efficient ways to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You could look to use the `fork` and `execl` family of calls although these are tied down to Unix / Linux and, depending on how you use them, are arguably no safer than system.

I doubt very much that you'll find a common, cross platform way of doing this if only because all platforms will have different and unique ways of doing this. Also, the scripts you're trying to run will no doubt have to be different on different platforms and there may be different ways of specifying things such as directory paths etc.

My suggestion would be to first ask yourself how you'll take the following questions - which would be my main concerns:

- How am I going to prevent accidental / intentional misuse?
- How am I going to detect errors or success status within the scripts I'm running?
- How am I going to provide for dependencies? E.g. script A must run completely and correctly before script B runs.
- How am I going to report the success and failure state.

My final question would be why do you want to do this in C++? Is there a specific reason? Naturally I'm a C++ evangelist although I would have thought this would be better tackled by a scripting language such as Perl, Python or possibly Bash unless you're embarking on something far more radical.

Comment: I making a editor for a game engine and I want the editor to have a build menu were you build out the games source. C++ is the language the editor is written in. Could I embed python in c++ and use that?

Comment: You could embed it but I doubt it would give you much advantage so you're probably better off using `fork` and `execl` in this instance. I would concentrate on (a) the input side - how you're going to nail down any variables, paths switches etc to reduce the chance of failure and (b) the output side - how can you catch, interpret and present the build output to accurately inform your user what happened?